# "Shared" variables in Modelica

Tags: modelica

i am working on a simulation in Modelica and i need an array to be shared by two blocks, i.e. both of them can modify the array's content. Something similar to this

```
block B1
INOUTCONNECTORIMLOOKINGFOR array[N];
parameter Integer i = 1;
algorithm 

when sample(0,T) then
array[i] := x;
i := i + 2;

end when;
end B1;


block B2
INOUTCONNECTORIMLOOKINGFOR array[N];
parameter Integer i = 2;
algorithm 

when sample(0,T) then
array[i] := x;
i := i + 2;

end when;
end B2;
```

How is it possible to achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest another design.
In your example instances of `B1` write the uneven indices in array (start value of 1, incremented by 2)
and instances of `B2` the even indices.
I see at least two major issues here:

1. Multiple instances of `B1` or `B2` would write to the same index
   (assuming default parameters).
2. If the model gets bigger, it will be very hard to debug. How do you know who is currently writing the signal, without digging deep in the result file?

Ignoring those issues, you could use the inner/outer feature of Modelica, but in an untypical way involving connectors and connect statements. The outer component defines the array connector (the shared variable) and the inner components connect to it to write their values. However, this solution still has the issues mentioned above.

#### Alternative solution

Instead of using a shared variable, use a single component which stores all signals.
This makes it much easier to follow where signals are written.
Connect the signals to store from other blocks via inputs.

The example below demonstrates what I mean.

- We can have an arbitrary amount of instances of `B` which are connected to the buffer.
- You must specify the buffer size for the history and the number of components to connect
- The buffer has one line per input signal and one column for the history
- When the buffer is full, we have to do something. Here I just reset the index to 1.

```
model Example
  B b1(k=1);
  B b2(k=2);
  B b3(k=3);
  Buffer buffer(
    n_signals=3,
    buffer_size=5,
    T=0.1);
equation 
  connect(b1.x, buffer.x[1]);
  connect(b2.x, buffer.x[2]);
  connect(b3.x, buffer.x[3]);
end Example;

block B
  import Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput;
  parameter Real k = 1;
  RealOutput x = time*k;
end B;

block Buffer
  import Modelica.Units.SI;
  import Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput;
  parameter Integer n_signals "Number of input signals";
  parameter Integer buffer_size "Number of values to store at same time";
  parameter SI.Time T "Sampling time";
  Real array[n_signals, buffer_size](each start=0, fixed=true) "Buffered values";
  RealInput x[n_signals] "Values to store";
protected 
  Integer i(start=1);
algorithm 
  when sample(0, T) then
    array[:, i] := x;
    i := if i < buffer_size then i + 1 else 1;
  end when;
end Buffer;
```